# Confusion regarding sudo apt-get purge make

Tags: uninstall

I tried to uninstall make because I wanted to see something and I did

`sudo apt-get purge make`

the thing is that in the uninstall process it showed a warning and some weird packages being uninstalled (for example some containing the name nvidia).

Did I uninstall anything crucial for the system by mistake?

The contents of the last `apt-get` command:

```
Start-Date: 2015-05-08  10:06:02 Commandline: apt-get purge make Install: ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 (2.1.3-4, automatic) Purge: make:amd64 (3.81-8.2ubuntu3), dkms:amd64 (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04), equivs:amd64 (2.0.9), dpkg-dev:amd64 (1.17.5ubuntu5.4), hardening-includes:amd64 (2.5ubuntu2.1), debhelper:amd64 (9.20131227ubuntu1), nvidia-331:amd64 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4), nvidia-libopencl1-331:amd64 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4), bbswitch-dkms:amd64 (0.7-2ubuntu1), lintian:amd64 (2.5.22ubuntu1), nvidia-prime:amd64 (0.6.2), build-essential:amd64 (11.6ubuntu6), nvidia-331-uvm:amd64 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) End-Date: 2015-05-08  10:07:07

Start-Date: 2015-05-08  10:07:36 Commandline: apt-get autoremove Remove: screen-resolution-extra:amd64 (0.17.1), libautodie-perl:amd64 (2.23-1), libfile-fcntllock-perl:amd64 (0.14-2build1), libgettextpo-dev:amd64 (0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3), libnet-domain-tld-perl:amd64 (1.70-1), lib32gcc1:amd64 (4.9.1-0ubuntu1), libio-string-perl:amd64 (1.08-3), libgettextpo0:amd64 (0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3), t1utils:amd64 (1.37-2ubuntu1), libcuda1-331:amd64 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4), nvidia-settings:amd64 (331.20-0ubuntu8), libasprintf-dev:amd64 (0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3), libnet-ip-perl:amd64 (1.26-1), libperlio-gzip-perl:amd64 (0.18-1build3), liblist-moreutils-perl:amd64 (0.33-1build3), diffstat:amd64 (1.58-1), intltool-debian:amd64 (0.35.0+20060710.1), libnet-dns-perl:amd64 (0.68-1.2build1), libipc-system-simple-perl:amd64 (1.25-2), libemail-valid-perl:amd64 (1.192-1), libdpkg-perl:amd64 (1.17.5ubuntu5.4), po-debconf:amd64 (1.0.16+nmu2ubuntu1), libapt-pkg-perl:amd64 (0.1.29build1), libsub-identify-perl:amd64 (0.04-1build3), libipc-run-perl:amd64 (0.92-1), gettext:amd64 (0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3), libarchive-zip-perl:amd64 (1.30-7), patchutils:amd64 (0.3.2-3), libc6-i386:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.6), libio-pty-perl:amd64 (1.08-1build4), libclone-perl:amd64 (0.36-1), libtext-levenshtein-perl:amd64 (0.06~01-2), libvdpau1:amd64 (0.7-1), dh-apparmor:amd64 (2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.1), libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 (1.2.0-1ubuntu1) End-Date: 2015-05-08  10:08:05
```

Comment: Post the content of the last `apt-get` command in `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Comment: @kos I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by ejno, it's fine: nVidia drivers depend on `make`, because `make` is needed to build the modules against the current kernel on installation / kernel upgrades: removing `make` without removing the nVidia drivers would have left the nVidia drivers' package "broken", so they were removed by `apt-get`.

Comment: The first command returns "command not found" and the second installs nothing.

Comment: @Adam Have you ever installed the nVidia proprietary drivers?

Comment: Yes the proprietary and tested one. Now I went to search for drivers and it says that I use the open source one and not the nvidia which I had installed!

Comment: @Adam Then you'll have to reinstall them, quickest way is from the "Additional Drivers" application

Comment: @Adam Yep, somehow `ap-get` messed up this time

Comment: That is what I am doing now. That is the first thing that I did when I installed Ubuntu. Thank you.

Comment: @ejno Thanks, that indeed makes sense. I updated my answer according to this