# Uninstalling Dependencies. Is This a Good Practice?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, dependencies

As far as I know I can uninstall a program from Ubuntu using this command...

```
$ sudo dpkg -r packagename
```

But this does not remove the dependencies while the `packagename` installed. To remove all files including dependencies we need to apply this command...

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove packagename
```

But my question is removing the package and all its dependencies is really a good practice? Will `--purge autoremove` command make my system as it before installing the `packagename` package? Or occasionally I might end up with some broken files and my system might crash while trying to remove everything? Actually I am afraid to implement the `--purge autoremove` command and want to know expert opinion before practising this!

Comment: `autoremove` doesn't require a package name after it.

Comment: @saiarcot895 if so then how terminal will know which package to remove?

Comment: It will remove all packages that, according to its database, were automatically installed for a package that is no longer installed. (In other words, if a package is marked as being automatically installed, but no other package depends on that package, then it's marked for removal.)

Comment: On a related note, check out `deborphan`, it will search out (and list, only) unnecessary packages more thoroughly than `apt-get autoremove`. Though if you have non-Ubuntu software (like, built from sources) where you manually installed dependecies, be careful with `deborphan` results, it may list something you want to keep.

Comment: @saiarcot895 well I think I misunderstood something. I thought I need to use only `$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove packagename` this command when I want to remove a package and all its dependencies. But after reading you comments now I thing in fact I need to apply 2 commands to remove a package and its deps. First of all the `$ sudo dpkg -r packagename` command to remove the package and then `$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` command to clear the deps including all unremoved deps. Am I right? Please confirm me.

Comment: @hyde when I write the command deborphan I see a message that the program deborphan is currently not installed!

Comment: @MikeFriedman Yes, recent versions of Ubuntu (and probably most distros) have bash hooks, which suggest possible commands when you enter command/program which isn't found. It may also suggest packages, when there's no exact match (try `deborphans` for example).

Comment: @MikeFriedman: I recommend that you use `apt-get` whenever possible rather than using both `apt-get` and `dpkg` (the exception being if you're installing a deb file, in which case you'll need to use `dpkg`). To remove a package using `apt-get`, it's just `sudo apt-get remove packagename`. I just did a test, and you can indeed use `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove packagename` to remove the package and any unused packages you have (after removing the package).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be quite safe. Autoremove removes only packages, which were installed by dependency of a removed package. They should not be needed.
You are correct. Your system should be as before you installed 'packagename'.

Answer (score 2):

Autoremove only removes ***orphaned*** packages. Meaning that it is completely safe to use without disrupting any functional or currently installed programs.

Comment: I wouldn't say "completely safe", more like 99,5% safe: Non-Ubuntu programs may depend on libraries, which are installed as dependencies of some Ubuntu programs. So if you autoremove the Ubuntu program, it removes the lib, and non-Ubuntu program also stops working. Of course this is rather trivial to fix by figuring out which library got removed, and explicitly installing it with `apt-get install` (then autoremove will not remove it).

Answer (score 2):

It is quite safe most of the times, but when you use it you must check your terminal for the names of the packages that are about to be removed because sometimes errors happen. Do not agree to the removal of dependencies without having double checked the names of the packages that are about to be removed and see if there is any that shouldn't normally be there. Check [what happened](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620913/confusion-regarding-sudo-apt-get-purge-make) to me a few days before.

Comment: Although I agree with the advice to take a look at the packages that will be removed before pressing `y` when running `sudo apt-get autoremove`, [what happened to you](http://askubuntu.com/questions/620913/confusion-regarding-sudo-apt-get-purge-make) doesn't seem to be an example of this. This question is about removing packages that were installed as dependencies but are no longer needed. In your case, it was about removing a package that *still was* a dependency of another installed package. (In your case, if there was an inadvertently removed package it was the *reverse dependency*.)

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes I agree. I wrote that answer in order to point out that you should always check as there is the possibility of errors. I mention my experience only to depict that errors do happen with the `apt-get` not to link it with what the OP asks. It is just a side note. :P